# How i display username after login successful with set cookies using angular nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

My login.component.ts file

How to set cookies in the code to display the username.

```
login Submit(){
  
      console.log(this.userLogin.value)
      this.service.LoginData(this.userLogin.value).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
        this.userLogin.reset()
        this.successmsg = res.message
        this.Username = this.cookieService.set('username', this.Username)
      })
     
    
  }
```

I am trying to display the username but it only see me undefined.

api service file

```
LoginData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/login`,data)
  }
  dashboard(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/dashboard')
  }
```

NodeJS file using MySQL database

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
  
    const query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '${username}' AND password = '${password}'`;
  
    db.query(query, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error querying database:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error querying database');
      } else if (result.length === 0) {
        console.log('Invalid username or password');
        res.status(401).send('Invalid username or password');
      } else {
        console.log('Login successful');
        res.status(200).send({
          message: 'Login successful',
          username: username
        });
      }
    });
    res.cookie('username',`${username}`)
  });
```

Comment: Where is the code wherever you are trying to display the username?
Also, are you sure if cookies are coming from the server? check the network inside the tab, the API call response header should return the cookie also if ur code is correct than u can also see it in the cookie tab inside the dev tools of the browser.  investigate the problem first